# The jQuery blurring code affects the whole block

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I'm trying to customize my wordpress theme. I want a parallax header with a fixed background and I want it to blur as people scrolling the web page up. This is the CSS code of my header:

```
/*HEADER PARALLAX*/
.site-header .site-header-bottom {
    background-image: url("../bg.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto; 
}
```

so I added this function to my javascript section of theme:

```
function blurHeader(){
    var pxlCount = 0
    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        pxlCount = $(document).scrollTop()/50;
        $(".site-header .site-header-bottom img")
            .css({
                "-webkit-filter": "blur("+pxlCount+"px)",
                "-moz-filter": "blur("+pxlCount+"px)",
                "filter": "blur("+pxlCount+"px)" 
            })     
    });
}
```

But it affects everything on the header (including title and description). I want it only blurs the background. It also behaves really weird on mobile version. Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: This is the default behaviour, assuming the title and description are child elements of the header. Filters will affect the element you call it on, as well as any other child element. If you don't want this to happen you'll need to restructure your HTML

Comment: It's worth to mention that the blur effect is really heavy on browsers, that could be what causes the "weird" behavior on mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea, but as was pointed out in the comments, when you use filter:blur it blurs the contents of the element as well as the background.

Here's one approach using absolute positioning:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wxeRrM

Simplified HTML from the pen:

```
<div class="site-header">
    <div class="site-header-content">Content here</div>
    <div class="site-header-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Simplified CSS:

```
.site-header {
  height: 500px; /* Make sure to set a height */
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.site-header-content {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.site-header-bottom {
  background: url('https://placeimg.com/640/480/any'); /* Your image */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You loaded the background image in `css` why would you use `img` tag in jquery

`$(".site-header .site-header-bottom img").css({..})`

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .site-header{
        width: 100%;
        height: 1500px;
    }
    .site-header .site-header-bottom {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background-image: url("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: auto;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var pxlCount = 0
        $(window).on('scroll', function () {
            pxlCount = $(document).scrollTop()/50;
            $(".site-header .site-header-bottom").css({"-webkit-filter": "blur("+pxlCount+"px)","-moz-filter": "blur("+pxlCount+"px)","filter": "blur("+pxlCount+"px)" })     
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="site-header">
    <h1>This is the title.</h1>
    <p>This is the text.</p>
    <div class="site-header-bottom"></div>
</div>
```